# Error transferring database from MySql to Postgres using mysql2pgsql

Tags: python, mysql, django, heroku-postgres, mysql2psql-gem

In order to host my Python/Django app on Heroku, I'm trying to convert my db from MySQL to Postgres following the instructions on https://realpython.com/blog/python/migrating-your-django-project-to-heroku/. I'm currently running OSX 10.9, and am using the tool mysql2pgsql to make the transfer.

When I try to run the command "`py-mysql2pgsql -v -f mysql2pgsql.yml`" to actually transfer the db, it copies over the first three tables, and then hits a snag on auth_user, returning the error "`raise Exception('unknown %s' % column['type']) Exception: unknown datetime(6)`". This seems strange, because auth_user is generated by one of Django's default installed apps, so I wouldn't expect it to cause any errors.

Any idea what could be causing this error or what I should be doing differently? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the directory 'Lib\site-packages\py_mysql2pgsql-0.1.6-py2.7.egg\mysql2pgsql\lib' edit the like 76 postgres_writer.py file 
as

from

```
 elif column['type'] == 'datetime':
```

to

```
elif column['type'] == 'datetime' or column['type'].startswith('datetime('):
```

I was facing the same problem, this solution worked for me.