# Edit package installed by pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to edit a package that I installed via pip, called py_mysql2pgsql (I had an error when converting my db from mysql to postgre, just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008398/error-transferring-database-from-mysql-to-postgres-using-mysql2pgsql).

However, when I got to the folder /user/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py_mysql2pgsql-0.1.5.egg-info, I cannot find the source code for the package. I only find PKG-INFO and text files.

How can I find the actual source code for a package (or in particular, this package)?

Thanks

Comment: I believe pip deletes it after install:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617198/pip-creates-build-directories

Comment: Hmm so I need to edit the code for that package because there is a bug... do you have any idea how I could do that?\

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. You can find where pip installed the package using `pip show py_mysql2pgsql`

Answer (score 10):

## TL;DR:

Modifying in place is dangerous. Modify the source and *then* install it from your modified version.

## Details

pip is a tool for managing the installation of packages. You should not modify files creating during package installation. At best, doing so would mean pip will believe that a particular version of the package is installed when it isn't. This would not interact well with the upgrade function. I suspect pip would just overwrite your customizations, discarding them forever, but I haven't confirmed. The other possibility is that it checks if files have changed and throws an error if so. (I don't think that's likely.) It also misleads other users of the system. They see that you have a package installed, but you don't actually have that version indicated; you have a customized version. This is likely to result in confusion if they try to install the unmodified version somewhere else or if they expect some particular behavior from the version installed.

If you want to modify the source code, the right thing to do is *modify the source code* and either build a new, custom package or just install from source. [py-mysql2pgsql](https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql) provides instructions for performing a source install:

```
> git clone git://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql.git
> cd py-mysql2pgsql
> python setup.py install
```

You can clone the source, modify it, and then install without using pip. You could alternatively build your own customized version of the package if you need to redistribute it internally. This project uses setuptools for building its packages, so you only need to familiarize yourself with setuptools to make use of their `setup.py` file. Make sure that installing it this way doesn't create any misleading entries in pip's package list. If it does, either find a way to make sure the entry is more clear or find an alternative install method.

Since you've discovered a bug in the software, I also highly recommend forking it on Github and submitting a pull request once you have it fixed. If you do so, you can use the above installation instructions just by changing the repository URL to your fork. If you don't fork it, at least file an issue and describe the changes that fix it.

Alternatives:

- You could copy all the source code into your project, modify it there, and then distribute the modified version with the rest of your code. (Make sure you don't violate the license if you do so.)
- You might be able to solve you problem at runtime. Monkey-patching the module is a little risky if other people on your team might not expect the change in behavior, but it could be done for global modification of the module's behavior. You could also create some additional code that *wraps* the buggy code: it can take input, call the buggy code, and either prevents or handles the bug (e.g., modifying the input to make it work or catching an exception and handling it, etc.).

Answer (score 8):

just print out the `.__file__` attribute of the module:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__file__
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'
```

Obviously the path and specific package would be different for you but this is pretty fool proof way of tracking down the source file of any module in python.

Answer (score 2):

You can patch pip packages quite easily with the [`patch`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) command. Which is part of [GNU Diffutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) found in most GNU/Linux distros.

When you do this, it's important that you have a specific version installed of the package that you want to patch. Otherwise your patch might not work. Typically you would do this by using a Python Package manager like [Pipenv](https://docs.pipenv.org/), [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) or [PDM](https://pdm-project.org/). In this example I use Pipenv. It creates a lock file where all versions of all pip dependencies and sub-dependencies are locked, so that always the same versions of pip packages are installed. It also manages your virtual env, and makes it convenient to use the method described here.

The first argument to the `patch` command is the file you want to patch. So that should be the module of the pip package, which is probably inside a virtualenv.

If you use Pipenv, you can get the virtual env path with `pipenv --venv`, so then you could patch the `requests` package like this:

```bash
patch $(pipenv --venv)/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py < requests-api.patch
```

The `requests.patch` file is a patch file which looks similar to a (git) diff. It looks something like this:

```
--- requests/api.py     2022-05-03 21:55:06.712305946 +0200
+++ requests/api_new.py 2022-05-03 21:54:57.002368710 +0200
@@ -54,6 +54,8 @@
       <Response [200]>
     """

+    print(f"Executing {method} request at {url}")
+
     # By using the 'with' statement we are sure the session is closed, thus we
     # avoid leaving sockets open which can trigger a ResourceWarning in some
     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
```

You can make the patch file like this:

```bash
diff -u requests/api.py requests/api_new.py > requests-api.patch
```

Where `requests/api_new.py` would be the new, updated version of `requests/api.py`.

The `-u` flag to the `diff` command gives a unified diff format, which can be used to patch files later with the `patch` command.

So this method could be used in an automated process. Just make sure that you have specified an exact version numbers for the module that you patch. You don't want the module to upgrade unexpectedly, because you might have to update the patch file. So you also have to keep in mind, that if you ever manually upgrade the module, that you also check if the patch file needs to be recreated, and do so if it is necessary. It is only necessary when the file that you are patching has been updated in the new version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

`py_mysql2pgsql` package is hosted on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-mysql2pgsql

If you want the code for that specific version, just download the source tarball from PyPI (py-mysql2pgsql-0.1.5.tar.gz)

Development is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql