# Proper way to customize third-party python package in project

Tags: python, version-control, pip, package

To extend the capabilities of [whoosh](https://pypi.org/project/Whoosh/#files) - a full text indexing, search engine  library- to fit the needs of my project I need to edit the source and apply my changes to possible future releases.

There are several related questions on stackoverflow which seem to address this issue but I don't know how to apply that to my specific problem case:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23075617/5111904
- [Edit package installed by pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668773/edit-package-installed-by-pip)

My approach would be to download the whoosh source code and copy the folder `Whoosh-2.7.4/src/whoosh` into the project and edit the source code there without any installation.

How can I tackle this problem in a proper/better way?

Comment: I'd not do this. See if you can use other techniques; subclassing, monkeypatching, configuration, first. Only then fork the project; do so in a source control system so you can keep track of your changes versus project updates in the future, and create your own internal release. Both the answers you link to advocate the same when you do need to fork.

Comment: Woosh is [hosted on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/overview) so you can trivially create a fork there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right I should propably fork the project. Subclassing won't work because I don't specialize methods (instead I modify them) which would leed to many duplicate LOC - ty.